# PDF viewer in fragments?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, pdf

I've made an app and that includes fragments.My PDF viewer works perfectly fine but not in fragments.How can I fix that ? I have asset files and everything.Compiled git hub reference, XML just having trouble with fragments.Thank You

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);

            //pdfView = getView().findViewById(R.id.pdfView);
            //pdfView.fromAsset("tenor-madness.pdf").load();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab1, container, false);

    }
```

XML FİLE

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="liselimanyak.practice.Tag2">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

    <com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView
        android:id="@+id/pdfView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="tab1"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textSize="30dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't call `findViewById()` in `onCreate()` ....do it in `onCreateView` (using something like following)...or alternatively in `onViewCreated` (using the `view` param)

```
 View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab1, container, false;

 pdfView = v.findViewById(R.id.pdfView);
```

...or, if using `onViewCreated`

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    pdfView = view.findViewById(R.id.pdfView); 
    pdfView.fromAsset("tenor-madness.pdf").load();
}
```

Comment: can you confirm that `pdfView` is being set correctly?

Comment: public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab1, container, false);
        PDFView pdfView = (PDFView)v.findViewById(R.id.pdfView);
        pdfView.fromAsset("tenor-madness.pdf").load();
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab1, container, false);

    }

Comment: can you include `fragment_tab1.xml` in your question

Comment: Sure I've added.

Comment: @AylinGörgün I think you tried to edit my answer rather than your original question (just got notification about the edit request)

Comment: sorry my bad.I'm new here.

Comment: no problem...easy mistake to make.  So, nothing obvious jumping out....bit of shot in dark but can you try loading pdf in `onViewCreated` callback instead

Comment: But there is no method onViewCreated I've tried to rename onCreateView but than I've lost my text view too.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onViewCreated(android.view.View, android.os.Bundle)

Comment: How can I write this method ? They didnt put an example,thank you for your time.

Comment: Have edited my answer to include example of using `onViewCreated`

Comment: That's great to hear.  Happy Android Coding!